# Transferring Column Names into a new column and its values into another column

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this:
[image]

And I want to make it so that my output will be:

The "Year" Column will have values of 2001,2002,2003.....

The "Values" Column will have the values from the respective years

Apologies in advance, I'm new to R studio and I've been stuck on this question for a long time.

Comment: You should use e.g. `tidyr::pivot_longer`

Comment: @Maël Lemme try to understand the dplyr method first, because my lecturer hasn't taught me anything about reshape yet. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Bryan the most up to date way you a to use https://stackoverflow.com/a/57939670/5784757 - it’s a tidyr way not a dplyr way.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer thanks to @Mael [Reshaping data.frame from wide to long format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format)

I did it by using the pivot_longer function

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(data= df4,
             cols = c("2001":"2050"),
             values_to = "Values"
             names_to = "Year")
```